# migrating to OpenRIAService

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

As I upgraded my EntityFramework from EF 5 with Legacy ObjectContext to EF 6 with T4, I'm also forced to the OpenRIAService. So far I followed the [Blog post](http://www.openriaservices.net/blog/post/The-Open-RIA-Services-Blog/1017/Porting-from-WCF-RIA-Services-to-Open-RIA-Services/).

Unfortunately, I'm having a problem in all of my DomainServices.
Here is the Error Message in German

> Der Typ 'DatabaseModel.MyEntities' kann nicht als Typparameter 'TContext' im generischen Typ oder in der generischen Methode 'OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.LinqToEntitiesDomainService' verwendet werden. Es ist keine implizite Verweiskonvertierung von 'DatabaseModel.MyEntities' in 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext' vorhanden.

Here is my translation to english

> The type 'DatabaseModel.MyEntities' can not be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.LinqToEntitiesDomainService'. There exist no implicit conversion from 'DatabaseModel.MyEntities' in 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext'.

Seems like it wanted to have ObjectContext, maybe you have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had derive from DbDomainService instead of LinqToEntitiesDomainService in the class definition.